# How to animate hover effect by CSS3

Tags: css

I resize an image by hover effect as

```
<img id="image" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" align="middle" alt="Img1"/>

#image{
    height:50px;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s;
    transition: height 2s;
}

#image:hover{
    height:100%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nwxutpvs/1/)

How should I adjust the code to make the transformation with a gradual animation?

Comment: height 100% will only increase the element height if it's parent element has a fixed size using `px, em, etc` as opposed to `%, vwh`

Comment: you could also look in to `jQuery's animate()`.  I've found it fantastic for a variety of animations - http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you have only applied `height` values to the image while you attempt to apply a smooth transition to its `width`. Either use `height` or `all` for the transition.

Secondly, you attempt to make the new image height `100%`. Now, 100% of what? Either specify a fixed height in pixels, or put it inside a container with a fixed height.

So either do:

```css
#image {
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: height 2s;
}
#image:hover {
    height: 100px; /* Height set in a fixed unit such as pixels */
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" align="middle" alt="Img1"/>
```

Or wrap the image in a container with a fixed height:

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
#image {
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* Safari */
    transition: height 2s;
}
#image:hover {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img id="image" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" align="middle" alt="Img1"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try scale transition:

CSS:

```
#image {
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

#image:hover {
  transform: scale(2);//Can be any value
  transition: all 0.2s height: auto;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nwxutpvs/2/

Comment: It does what I want, but the transform creates an absolute position. Then, as you can see in the fiddle, the image goes outside the frame.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want CSS' transition.  Try something like this:

```
#image{
    height:50px;
    transition: height 2s; // specify property and duration
}

#image:hover {
    max-height: 500px; // new height
    transition: linear; // evenly timed transition
}
```

Comment: Your solution, keeps the resized format for 0.25s after hover. I want to animate the process of resizing.

Comment: haha, sorry.  Was confused - it's been a long day :)  I'll update in a mo